# EasyMock: How to mock map of Objects

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I am new to EasyMock, tried searching solution to my problem but cudn't find. I have a class "Student" which has several attributes one being "student_id", it has all setter and getter methods . I have written a function like this which takes Map of Student objects as key and value is their CGPA, it returns a Map having top 5 students by CGPA.

```
Map<Student,Double>  getMaxCPAStudent(Map<Student,Double>)
```

In my test class I write:

```
control = EasyMock.createControl();
mockStudent = control.createMock(Student.class);
```

But while putting them in Map with different scores they will all have the same key, how to test this function ??

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: I'm slightly confused by what you are trying to test. Are you testing that the `getMaxCPAStudent` method returns the correct results or are you testing that the provided map is searched as you expect? I wonder if you should be mocking the `Map` and not the `Student`...

Answer (score 0):

I think that EasyMock overrides `hashcode()` and `equals()` in its mocks so creating multiple mock Students will never have the same hash.  This means you should be able to put them all in a Map just fine.

So your test code shouldn't be any different than if you were writing production code with this method.  Create some mock students, put them in a Map and then call your max method to get a new map back and check that the keys and values are correct.

slightly off topic, unless you are using an *Ancient* version of Easymock, you should never have to deal with MockControl class.

```
Student mockStudent = EasyMock.createMock(Student.class);
```

Should work just fine.